# CKEDITOR.instance[x].setData not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Ok, I'm using the CKEditor in a web application. One thing I need to do it set the text in the text area. I've been using the line:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.setData(html);
```

...where `html` is a varible containing HTML.

This works fine in Chrome & Firefox, but not at all in Internet Explorer or Safari.

Can anyone provide an insight as to why, or suggest a work-around?

Many thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Amendment to my question; this DOES work in Safari - just not IE...

Comment: That code ('CKEDITOR.instances.setData(html);
') should fail in all the browsers because you're not stating the instance that you want to use. Once that fixed it should work just the same unless you're trying to use a bad html string that can't be parsed by IE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to strip all newlines from the string you pass into `setData().` An exception is thrown if you don't, with a message about an unterminated string. The newline characters used by `CKEditor` are the UNIX-style of `\n` (in other words, not the DOS version: `\r\n`).

The newline apparently throws off the parser, making it think that it's the end of the statement.

Also note that if you call `getData()` to get that value you just set again, `CKEditor` puts the line breaks and tabs back into it. You'll need to strip them out again if you need to set that value back using `setData().` I use a regexp pattern like this to strip out the newlines (and tabs just for completeness):

```
[\n\t]+
```

Also make sure that if you use the regular expression to strip them, you need to make sure that the pattern matching will match the `\n` character (called "single-line" mode in .NET, but I don't know what you're using).